# getting "NOT FOUND" when using blueprints

Tags: python, html, flask, routes

i am getting "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." when using blue prints

my app.py code is below,please have a look

```
__author__ = 'mullapudi'
from flask import Flask,request,redirect,Blueprint,render_template

blueprint = Blueprint('app', __name__, url_prefix='/login')

@blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin_login():
    # Located at https://yourdomain.com/login
    return render_template('admin_login.html')

@blueprint.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # Located at https://yourdomain.com/login/login
    return  render_template('admin_login.html')
```

my `__init__.py` code is below

```
from flask import Flask,request,Blueprint
from app import blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

app.run()
```

my html code is below,my form is like this

```
<form action="{{url_for('app.login')}}" method="post">
```

now is there any wrong with my code,please help me ,my structure is

```
/sample ->>project name
    /static
    /templtes-->>html codes are here
    __init__.py
    app.py
```

EDIT

it is working for url localhost:5000/login/
but it is not working for localhost:5000/login/login/

```
@blueprint.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # Located at https://yourdomain.com/login/login
    un = request.form['un']
    pwd = request.form['pwd']
    print un,pwd
    if verify_from_database(un,pwd):
        print "admin authentication successful"
        return render_template('adminPage1.html')

@blueprint.route('/addnew/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def adminPage1():
    # Located at https://yourdomain.com/login/addnew
    return  render_template('example.html')
```

and the form of adminPage1.html is

```
 <form action="{{url_for('app.addnew')}}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your blueprint uses a *prefix*. You'll need to include this prefix when accessing the routes.

Since you use `url_prefix='/login'` you need to look for `/login/` (for the `/` route) and `/login/login/` (for the `/login/` route).

Note that your `login()` function appears to return `None` if `verify_from_database()` returns a false value. You need to *always* return a valid response from a view (or raise an exception). This is not the cause of your 404 error however.

Comment: sir,please can not understand what u r saying,can please explain me in detail,i am beginner to this

Comment: I'm not sure what part you don't understand though. It would help if you s showed (in your question, you can edit it) what URL you entered into your browser that gave you the 404 error.

Comment: sir i had updated my query initially it worked for /login/ and it is not working for /login//login/

Comment: @learner: the code, as posted, works. I can access both the `/login/` and the `/login/login/` URLs (note that there is just **one** slash between the two `login` parts). The `url_for()` call also works and returns `/login/login/`.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2015 14:07:30] "POST /login/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
 it is giving "Internal Server Error" in web page ,the above is the output of console

Comment: @learner: that is *not* a NotFound response. That is a server error. You have a programming mistake somewhere, perhaps in the `verify_from_database()` function. You need to always include the actual error messages in your questions. Run flask in debug mode, add `debug=True` to the `app.run()` call: `app.run(debug=True)` to see the traceback in the browser.

Comment: no sir,verify_from_database() is absolutely right and getting output that returned is absolutely right

Comment: sorry,sir it is working fine after adding debug=True,thanks for your help